# Convert Base64 encoded md5 to a readable String

Tags: java, string, base64, md5

I have a password stored in ldap as md5 hash: `{MD5}3CydFlqyl/4AB5cY5ZmdEA==`
By the looks of it, it's base64 encoded.
How can i convert byte array received from ldap to a nice readable md5-hash-style string like this: `1bc29b36f623ba82aaf6724fd3b16718` ?
Is `{MD5}` a part of hash or ldap adds it and it should be deleted before decoding?

I've tried to use commons base64 lib, but when i call it like this:

```
String b = Base64.decodeBase64(a).toString();
```

It returns this - `[B@24bf1f20`. Probably it's a wrong encoding, but when i convert it to UTF-8 i see unreadable chars.
So, what can i do to solve this?

Comment: Just to clarify something here for you. The string "[B@24bf1f20" is the object type ID and memory address of the byte array that decodeBase64 returns. In other words the byte array begins at memory location 0x24bf1f20. Just to be really clear: this number is not data, it is a memory address.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the above answer was for C#, as there is no such AppendFormat method for the StringBuilder class in Java.

Here is the correct solution:

```
public static String getMd5Hash(String str) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException
{
  MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
  byte[] thedigest = md.digest(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));

  StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 0; i < thedigest.length; i++)
  {
      String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & thedigest[i]);
      if (hex.length() == 1)
          hexString.append('0');

      hexString.append(hex);
  }

  return hexString.toString().toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

decodeBase64 returns an array of bytes

To convert it to string of hex digits:

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
  StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
  foreach (byte b in ba)
    hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
  return hex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I don't need hex digits, i need string like this - 1bc29b36f623ba82aaf6724fd3b16718 - to be stored as md5 hash

Comment: Uh, scuse me but "1bc29b36f623ba82aaf6724fd3b16718" are hex digits. Are you asking how to hash the byte array or are you asking how to turn the byte array into a readable string of hex digits (such as 1bc29...)?

Comment: Ok, sorry, i'm an idiot and you are right. Maybe i should use commons Hex.EncodeHex(byte[]) then? As far as i can see it will do the same job as your code, but without me adding additional code.

Comment: You can add third party code, but why bloat your software with additional libs when you can do the same thing with 5 lines of code? Also, when it is your code you know exactly what it is doing and you can change it if need be, something you can't do with 3rd party code.