# Convert base64 encoded md5 back to its original hash value in powershell

Tags: powershell, hash

(Disclaimer: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823079/convert-base64-encoded-md5-to-a-readable-string) is what I'm asking but I do not fundamentally understand how they are achieving the result so I do not know how to replicate the process in Powershell.)

Basically, I have a series of Base64 encoded MD5 hashes (e.g `1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==`) but I need to convert them back to whatever format MD5 is in (e.g. `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`) in Powershell.

I can recreate the encoding process in powershell:

```
$string = ""
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($string)
$Hasher = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
$md5 = $Hasher.ComputeHash($bytes)
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($md5)
```

But I cannot figure out how to go the other way.

How can I do this?

Comment: `[BitConverter]::ToString( [Convert]::FromBase64String( '1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==' ) ).Replace( '-', '' ).ToLower()`. Or just replace `$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($md5)` with `$hex = [BitConverter]::ToString( $md5 ).Replace( '-', '' ).ToLower()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these functions with the []:: syntax are basic .NET methods. You can just refer to the documentation for the System.Convert class on MSDN.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string(v=vs.110).aspx

If you look at the methods on that page that mention Base64 you will find a method aptly named FromBase64String. You can just call that on the `$base64` variable to get back a byte array equivalent to the original `$md5` variable.

```
$md5FromBase64 = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($base64)
```

Comment: Ahh so simple! Thank you! For future readers I would like to note that this doesn't get you all the way to the hashed string, you have to use [BitConverter]::ToString($md5FromBase64.Replace( '-', '' ).ToLower() to get there. Thanks also to @PetSerAl

Comment: My mistake. I misunderstood "convert them back to whatever format MD5 is in" to mean a byte array. I'll add the conversion to string for completeness.